# Collection for storing blocked lines

Tags: java, collections

I am making an application where users will be typing on a shared document over a network. 
One of the issues is blocking lines that other users are typing in.
To do that I have a `DocumentListener` that is checking for line changes. When a user successfully moves to a new line (which means that line is not used) the listener will notify other users that the line is now used.

A `DocumentFilter` will check each time an edit is made if that line is blocked, before allowing it.

Now, one of my concerns is what kind of collection is most appropriate for storing the line numbers. The collection will be holding just `Integer`. When a line is blocked it will be added to that collection. When the `DocumentFilter` needs to check if a line is available it will go through that list . Also when the user that was using that line moves to a new line, another message is send that will remove that line from the collection of users.

I am aware that an `ArrayList` will probably be enough although I was hoping someone might think different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashSet<Integer>` will outperform an `ArrayList<Integer>` by a large margin if you expect a large amount of Lookups and a large amount of blocked documents.

As far as i know worst case lookups(referring to "contains") are

- O(n) - `ArrayList`
- O(log2(n)) - `SortedList`
- O(1) - `HashSet` however this is related to the hash method ..

If you need to track additional data on a per lock basis you might consider to use a `HashMap<Integer, ILockInformation>`.

Answer (score 2):

What if a user adds a new line? Every stored line must be repositioned/renumbered.
And how about if a user exits the program or the program crashes or just he goes home for dinner? Are you implementing a timeout of some sort?

Anyhow, a SortedSet would do, but you maybe should store in the set item also the expiration time..

Comment: User can't add line in a similar way to a table. Lines can only be added in the end which doesn't oppose any problem. The thing about releasing lines after some time is something ill need to consider thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need unicity, a `List` is definitely not the right collection: you want a `Set`.